# Unable to write DVD-R(Blank DVD's)

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, nero

I have a problem in dvd drive i.e. It can read CD/DVD and can write CD and all CD/DVD-RW but cannot write DVD  DVD drive model is SH-S203B Samsung; I also have a log file created by nero burning rom 11.

Actually the fact is no Blank DVD's are being read in my dvd drive only previously written dvd's can be read! Is this the problem of OS or should I try cleaning the dvd drive or my DVD drive is 4yrs old so is it going to spoil now, since it is showing this type of symptoms!

OS = WinXP
AV = KIS 2012
DVD Drive = Samsung SH-S203B (Also tried latest firmware and downgrade versions also)

```
IA32
Nero Version: 11.2.4.100
Internal Version: 11,2,4,100

Recorder:             <TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-S203B>Version: SB04 - HA 1 TA 0 - 11.2.4.100
 Adapter driver:      <Serial ATA>              HA 1
 Drive buffer  :      2048kB
 Bus Type      :      via Inquiry data
CD-ROM:               <TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-S203B >Version: SB04 - HA 1 TA 0 - 11.2.4.100
 Adapter driver:      <Serial ATA>              HA 1

18:58:10    #37 SPTI -1511 File SCSIPassThrough.cpp, Line 224
    CdRom0: SCSIStatus(x02) WinError(0) NeroError(-1511)
    CDB Data:   0x28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 
    Sense Key:  0x04 (KEY_HARDWARE_ERROR)
    Sense Code: 0x3E
    Sense Qual: 0x02
    Sense Area: 0x70 00 04 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 3E 02 
    Buffer x08047340: Len x8000

18:58:10    #38 SectorVerify 20 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 12057
    Read errors from sector 0 to 14
    <Padding>

18:58:19    #39 SPTI -1511 File SCSIPassThrough.cpp, Line 224
    CdRom0: SCSIStatus(x02) WinError(0) NeroError(-1511)
    CDB Data:   0x28 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 10 00 
    Sense Key:  0x04 (KEY_HARDWARE_ERROR)
    Sense Code: 0x3E
    Sense Qual: 0x02
    Sense Area: 0x70 00 04 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 3E 02 
    Buffer x08047340: Len x8000

18:58:19    #40 SectorVerify 21 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 12057
    Read error at sector 15
    <Virtual Multisession Info>

18:58:19    #41 SectorVerify 20 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 12057
    Read errors from sector 16 to 18
    <Volume Structure Descriptor Sequence>

18:58:28    #42 SPTI -1511 File SCSIPassThrough.cpp, Line 224
    CdRom0: SCSIStatus(x02) WinError(0) NeroError(-1511)
    CDB Data:   0x28 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 10 00 
    Sense Key:  0x04 (KEY_HARDWARE_ERROR)
    Sense Code: 0x3E
    Sense Qual: 0x02
    Sense Area: 0x70 00 04 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 3E 02 
    Buffer x08047340: Len x8000
```

Comment: How old is the DVD Drive? Some could only do +R(W) or -R(W) (they are different) - Nero should be able to tell you the supported media types of the device.

Comment: My DVD Drive is 4 yrs old and it supports dvd-r has previously I used to write same type of dvd's. Is this an issue of OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is using dvd lens cleaner. The problem was caused due to accumulation of dust in the lens of dvd drive.

[Removing open session from dvd-rw](https://superuser.com/questions/463680/removing-open-session-from-dvd-rw)