# Removing 2nd OS from HDD

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have two WinXP installations on same drive because I thought my previous OS system file might be having problems, but the problem is not about OS. So, I just want to remove my 2nd installed OS.

How can I remove this 2nd installed OS, should I just delete the windows folder?

I just want to know the way to remove the 2nd OS safely and easily. I also want to remove it from the bootloader menu.

Both are winXP SP3.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure Blex's solution will work, **just make sure that the two XP installations are in different partitions** otherwise you will delete *both* OSs.

For a GUI way of removing the install (taken from [here](http://forum.soft32.com/windows/Win-XP-offered-boot-remove-ftopict326401.html)) try:

```
Click Start, right click My Computer, select properties,
Click the advanced tab,
Under Startup and Recovery,
Click the Settings Button,
Under System Startup, click the Edit button,
Under [Operating Systems]
Delete the Windows XP Operating system line
It is usually the second line.
```

That will remove the 2nd XP from the bootloader menu. You should then be able to simply delete the 2nd Windows folder as you said. AFAIK there is no reason that should cause problems but maybe some of the more windowsy SUs has a better idea?

Comment: Thanks @terdon Can you help me to solve this issue also please...http://superuser.com/questions/462803/unable-to-write-dvd-rblank-dvds#comment543560_462803

Comment: @FrozenKing I'd love to, but I haven't the foggiest idea what could be wrong in that case. Sorry :(