# Removing open session from dvd-rw

Tags: windows-7, dvd, dvd-burning, nero

[image]

As you can see from the above image, nero is showing some "session is open" in my DVD rewritable disc. The problem is whenever I erase the session it is not getting erased and I am unable to write the remaining part of the disc. 

So, the worst part is will I be able to use this dvd-rw again or now it's just a waste scrap?

Nero version is 11
OS win7 
AV is KIS2012
Dvd-rw is from Sony company
Dvd drive from samsung sh-s203b with latest firmware

Comment: *> So, the worst part is will I be able to use this dvd-rw again or now it's just a waste scrap?*   Of course you can reuse it; it’s **re-writable**. Just copy the data from it, erase it, then burn the data back to it properly, making sure to not select the *leave option* option.

Comment: The problem is that nero or windows is not able to erase it!!!I think this open session is causing problems for nero to erase.

Comment: No, there’s no reason that an open session should be a problem. An open session is not a bug, it’s a purposely designed feature. Maybe Windows just doesn’t *support* open sessions and Nero (which should) is [buggy](http://club.myce.com/f1/close-open-session-how-36757/). Try [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/): *Tools* → *Drive* → *Erase Disc*. You can also try to [close](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Close-or-finalize-a-CD-or-DVD) or [finalize](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725689.aspx) the session.

Comment: ImgBurn is throwing some errors just see the image file "http://s15.postimage.org/vsd3g1j8b/Img_Burn.jpg"

Comment: Clean any dirt/oil/etc. and check for scratches (you can use a scratch repair-kit if desired; I used one on a DVD+RW and it worked well). But first, it looks like you probably have some other DVD software that is intercepting commands to your drive, so check the [driver filters](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/1034/64367041kn0.png) to make sure that there is [nothing interfering](http://i47.servimg.com/u/f47/15/17/80/12/imgbur10.png) with your drive and remove their filters if not (of course this may cause the other program to not work, but if it’s messing with your system, it’s not good).

Comment: Thanks for helping but I came to know the problem. The problem is with my dvd drive :( . I erased this dvd-r from my friend's laptop dvd-drive and it worked.

Comment: Ah, that’s too bad. Is the drive old or was it used a *lot*? The laser tends to wear out over time, but you should be able to [adjust its gain](https://www.google.com/search?q=adjust+drive+laser+gain&safe=off) to allow it to work again for several more years.

Comment: The age of dvd drive is 6yrs; should I go for a repair or buy a new one or should I go for a dvd cleaner disc; since dvd drive is able to read data's from cd-r,rw and dvd-,dvd-rw. Will dvd drive cleaner will solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Synetech my dvd problem is solved thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem. The problem was not with the dvd drive but with the lens of dvd drive. Actually, this problem is caused by the accumulation of dust particles in the lens of the dvd drive.

So, to solve this problem I brought a dvd lens cleaner which had a tiny 2 brushes in the sides of the DVD disc which cost below 1$. And after using this, the dvd drive again started working fine.

"http://www.ebay.in/itm/Kyowa-Lens-Cleaner-DVD-VCD-VD-ACD-and-all-other-/180950876709?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item2a21834225#ht_5083wt_1135"

Comment: This past weekend I was looking for my brushed-lens-cleaner but couldn’t find it, so seeing your post reminded me. Thanks. (I don’t know where you got the <$1 part though because the one you linked to—and all the others I can find on eBay—are >$2USD/CAD.)